# "Reply-to" field in Laravel mail is not working

Tags: php, email, laravel

I need help to figure out how to set the `reply-to` field in `app/config/mail.php`. I'm using Laravel 4 and it's not working. This is my `app/config/mail.php`:

```
<?php

return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'sender@domain.com',
        'name' => 'E-mail 1'
    ],
    'reply-to' => [
        'address' => 'replyto@domain.com',
        'name' => 'E-mail 2'
    ],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'sender@domain.com',
    'password' => 'pwd',
    'pretend' => false,
);
```

Comment: I was searching about it in the swiftmailer docs, but haven't found anything about the "reply-to" field.

Comment: Change it to `reply_to` and should work from 5.4+

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Pretty sure it doesn't work this way.  You can set the "From" header in the config file, but everything else is passed during the send:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')
        ->replyTo('reply@example.com', 'Reply Guy')
        ->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

FWIW, the `$message` passed to the callback is an instance of `Illuminate\Mail\Message`, so there are various methods you can call on it:

- ->from($address, $name = null)
- ->sender($address, $name = null)
- ->returnPath($address)
- ->to($address, $name = null)
- ->cc($address, $name = null)
- ->bcc($address, $name = null)
- ->replyTo($address, $name = null)
- ->subject($subject)
- ->priority($level)
- ->attach($file, array $options = array())
- ->attachData($data, $name, array $options = array())
- ->embed($file)
- ->embedData($data, $name, $contentType = null)

Plus, there is a magic `__call` method, so you can run any method that you would normally run on the underlying SwiftMailer class.

Comment: That's sad! Reply-to is such a basic information, it could be set up in the mail.php conig file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your last words. How can __call method be useful for me?

Comment: Reply to is pretty common, true. But I believe most MTAs will default to the value of the "From" header is "Reply-To" isn't specified.

Comment: And the benefit of `__call()` just means that, if there is a method of the SwiftMailer class that isn't wrapped by Laravel (i.e. not in the list above), you can still use it. For example, `addTextHeader()`

Comment: I dont get it. How do i reply to a specific conversation or thread. Is there some kind of Message/Conversation/Thread ID to link it?

Comment: The `Reply-To` header specifies the email address that's used if you reply to a message.  The `In-Reply-To` and/or `References` headers should have the same value as the original message's `Message-Id` header, and that's how mail clients know to group conversations together in a thread. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.4 and http://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html

Comment: This answer is out-of-date :)

Answer (score 25):

It's possible since Laravel 5.3 to add a global reply. In your config/mail.php file add the following:

```
'reply_to' => [
    'address' => 'info@xxxxx.com',
    'name' => 'Reply to name',
],
```

Comment: This answer is correct and works even in Laravel 5.4 well. I think it can be marked as the correct answer to this question. Since the `env()` function has been introduced in recent versions and the `.env` file, it can also be used appropriately.

   `'reply_to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_REPLY_ADDRESS', 'email@domain.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_REPLY_NAME', 'Reply Name'),
    ],`

This answer works just fine.

Comment: For me it didn't work because I used the same ReplyTo address adres as the inbox address it went to. Thunderbird in that case ignores the replyTo address when you hit reply. DOH!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mailable and in my App\Mail\NewUserRegistered::class on the build function I'm doing this,

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->replyTo('email', $name = 'name')
                ->markdown('emails.admin_suggestion');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to customizing SwiftMailer Message - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-swiftmailer-message.

```
->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($senderEmail) {
    $message->getHeaders()
        ->addTextHeader('Return-Path', $senderEmail);
})
```