# How to Get Mail Delivery Failed data in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using `Mail::send()` function in **Laravel 5.1**. Sometimes it fails to deliver to the recipient. Now I need to get the mail delivery failed report into a specific email. I used **return-path and envelope sender** but failed to success

Here is my method :

```
Mail::send('email_template.common', array(),
        function($message)
        {
            $message->from('devdhaka404@gmail.com', 'ETSB DEV OPS');
            $message->to('123323232323dsererer@gmail.com');
            $message->subject('Subject 2');
            #$message->sender('-fselimppc@gmail.com');
            #$message->returnPath('selimppc@gmail.com');
        } );
```

Mail config:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'from' => array('address' => 'yahoo@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Site Admin'),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'devdhaka404@gmail.com',
'password' => '88888888',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

It does not work. The mail-delivery failed data is returning into my smtp gmail account "devdhaka404@gmail.com"
Please let me get your help " May I get mail delivery failed data into my specific email" ?

resource: ["Reply-to" field in Laravel mail is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633509/reply-to-field-in-laravel-mail-is-not-working)

Comment: you can look at the [api documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method_failures). it should be able to be called `Mail::failured()` just like `Mail::send(..)`. and also, i wonder if smtp gmail actually checks for address existence - i always used a local dummy smtp server like [fakeSMTP](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) to debug laravel mail.

Comment: @Tezla : Mail::failured() is not working. Its returning "array(0)". Please have a look.

Comment: sorry, my bad, tried [`$message->getSwiftMessage()->setReadReceiptTo('your@address.tld');`](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)? we had to dig a little deeper to report failing e-mail to another address.

Comment: @Tezla it does not work ::: __$message->getSwiftMessage()->setReadReceiptTo('me@selimreza.com');__   I think, I am  missing very basic term in config or in mail. May I add envelope sender email in __mail::send()__ as a optional param ???

Comment: well, e-mail delivery failure actually handled by smtp and swiftmail only tells them what to do - but there is no guarantee they'll do so. so, i'm out of idea.

Comment: @Tezla : Thank you so much. I think Swiftmail could help me. I am running on Swiftmail. I will let you know.