# Send email in reply of any email not working

Tags: laravel, email, lumen, swiftmailer

I have used below library to send email:

```
"illuminate/mail": "5.2.*"
```

My code to send email in reply of any email:

```
$sent = Mail::send([], [], function ($msg) use ($data) {
            $msg->from($data["from_address"], $data["from_name"])
                ->to($data["to_address"])->subject($data["subject"])->setBody($data["body"]);
            if (isset($data["cc_address"])) {
                $msg->cc($data["cc_address"]);
            }
            if (isset($data["bcc_address"])) {
                $msg->bcc($data["bcc_address"]);
            }
            if (isset($data["attachment"])) {
                foreach ($data["attachment"] as $attachment) {
                    $msg->attach($attachment['file'], $attachment['options']);
                }
            }
            if (isset($data["message_id"])) {
                $msg->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addCustomHeader("In-Reply-To", $data["message_id"]);
                $msg->addCustomHeader("References", $data["message_id"]);
            }
        });
```

Here I have passed message id of email on which I want to send reply in header but it gives me error as below:

```
FatalErrorException in EmailCompose.php line 121:
Call to undefined method Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderSet::addCustomHeader()
```

If I use method `addTextHeader` instead of `addCustomHeader` then it gives me below error:

```
ErrorException in Message.php line 296:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Swift_Message' does not have a method 'addTextHeader'
```

Please can you tell me how can I reply on any email?

---

as per suggestion I have change my code for below condition

```
if (isset($data["message_id"])) {
                $msg->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("In-Reply-To", $data["message_id"]);
                $msg->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("References", $data["referances"].$data["message_id"]);
            }
```

this code is allow me to send email but not in replay to the any email but it is sents email as new email

how to send email in replay to the any email.

please help me to resolve this issue , I will appreciate best answer.

---

I have found my solution,

change below,

```
$msg->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("References", $data["referances"].$data["message_id"]);
```

with

```
$msg->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("References", $data["referances"]." , ".$data["message_id"]);
```

and subject should be same as email on which you want to replay, only append "Re:" in the subject of email on which you want to reply

it resolve my issue

but another issue is how to get email body of previous emails in replay of email

Comment: do you mean reply ? this could help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633509/reply-to-field-in-laravel-mail-is-not-working

Comment: How about: `$msg->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("In-Reply-To", $data["message_id"]); $msg->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("References", $data["message_id"]);`

Comment: @YahyaUddin, let me check it  separately

Comment: @MuhittinCokelek , thanks , but it will not work for me

Comment: hi @YahyaUddin , it is not sending email in repaly , it is send email as new email

Comment: I have resolve my that issue, and I have update my question for that

Comment: there is another issue , which I have mentioned at last of email, if you have any solution for that then please suggest me