# How can I add reply to in Laravel aplication?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-mail

I started with the following code:

```php
Mail::to('mail@gmail.com')->send(new ContactFormMail($email_data));
```

This works fine, but I am not sure how can I add 'reply to' to this code.
Next thing I tried is:

```php
Mail::send('emails.contact-form', $email_data, function ($message) {
  $message->from('admin@laravel.com', 'Laravel');
  $message->to('admin@laravel.com');
  $message->replyTo('admin@laravel.com', 'Laravel');
});
```

This has the following problem:

> No hint path defined for [mail]...

In this case, if I remove `@component('mail::message')` from the mail view, the message is sent as it should, but it has no styling.
Finally, I do have this piece of code in my Mailable class:

```php
public function build()
{
  return $this->markdown('emails.contact-form');
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21633725/2693543 does this help you?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#configuring-the-sender. The section *Using A Global from Address* explains how you can easily add a `reply_to` address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that the first argument of `Mail::send` only accepts either a `view` email template or a `mailable` class. however, you passed in a `markdown` file. so it's not happy with it.

A simple solution is

```php
public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.contact-form')
        ->replyTo('admin@laravel.com', 'Laravel');
    }
```

```php
Mail::to('mail@gmail.com')->send(new ContactFormMail($email_data));
```